# How to makepkg a git repository outside of the file

Tags: shell, arch-linux, terminal, git, aur

I'm trying to build a file called `command.sh`, which will just host a series of terminal commands that will install the software I need when I decide to buy a new computer. Its just the convenience of automating the entire process of building up your system to your need.

How to do I `makepkg` a cloned git repository?  Say that I've cloned a repo from the AUR website and I want to `makepkg -fsri` to install the software.  How do I do that without `cd` into that directory?  The reason why I'm asking is because the script will run from my `~` directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the directory permanently, you can try something like this

```
$ sh -c "cd '$mydir' && makepkg -fsri"
```

This will create a new shell process to do the work and changes to the shell environment, including the working directory will happen for that process only.
Be careful of correctly nesting quotes to handle spaces in bash variables if you expand on this idea.

**Edit:** It seems makepkg does not support working outside the current directory as shown in the man page:

```
-p <buildscript>
    Read the package script buildscript instead of the PKGBUILD default; see PKGBUILD(5). The buildscript
    must be located in the directory makepkg is called from.
```

Comment: The only reason why I don't want to change the directory is because I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe it's still possible, but I don't know how. maybe you could append your question to demonstrate (minimally) why you cannot change the directory beforehand. Are the permissions insufficient?

Comment: Okay so then how do I go inside the directory through the shell script?

Comment: The `cd` (bultin) command changes the current working directory for the following commands. Since I do not know your specific constraints well enough, I can not be of more help. To build a package in another directory you most certainly want to change to that directory and you can isolate that change by using some kind of subshell. In bash, there is also the parenthesis syntax: `(cd mySubDirectory && echo $PWD)` which is more efficient that starting a new process directly. If this does not help, you can expand your question with a minimal example that shows the problem.